# how to vertically center img in this situation

Tags: html, css

how do i vertically center an img in this given situation?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9nNs.jpg

I've been trying to follow the code in the following link but perhaps because of the way divi builder and the current layout is setup its not working.

https://designpieces.com/2012/12/vertical-centering-image-in-a-div/

Comment: please provide ur code, then only we can find out the error

Comment: Here's a great resource on centering stuff https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: here is the exact situation presented in this example page i created: http://chooseside.com/testing-page/ ...thanks for the link michael, however i have already looked at it and still couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parent to `position: relative` then absolutely position the image with `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` to put it in the center.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: #aaa;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px; /* this isn't necessary */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg">
</div>
```

You can also use flexbox with `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to center the image in the middle

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px; /* this isn't necessary */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: i couldnt get it to work with that, this is my exact situation here http://chooseside.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=202&action=edit

Comment: @MudKip I'm not going to log in to your wp admin instance or dig through code on your website. That isn't the point of SO. It's your responsibility to share the relevant code with us so we don't waste one another's time. You should read about how to create a [mcve]. But I wouldn't recommend sending out links to your wp-admin. It doesn't work without your username and password, either, and please don't give that out to strangers on the internet.

Comment: sorry i linked the wrong thing: http://chooseside.com/testing-page/ ...didnt mean to link wp-admin, i would post this on jsfiddle but i might miss something as theres a lot of carried over css from other stuff going on in the site and im not good with coding to begin with

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `flex` property

```css
#content{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
background:#eee;}

#block2_2
{width:100%;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #111;
}

#block2_3
{width:100%;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
#block2
{width:50%;
height:600px;

}
#block3
{width:50%;
height:600px;
border:1px solid #000;
display:flex;
align-content:center;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;

}
#img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid #000;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div id="block2">
<div id="block2_2"></div>
<div id="block2_3"></div>
</div>
<div id="block3">
<div id="img"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/gs7nxnms/. Add this css:

```
#container {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
   display:-moz-box; 
-moz-box-pack:center; 
-moz-box-align:center; 

display:-webkit-box; 
-webkit-box-pack:center; 
-webkit-box-align:center; 

display:box; 
box-pack:center; 
box-align:center;
}

#container img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
 align-items: center;
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px; /* this isn't necessary */
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg">
</div>
```